# What's the Solaris equivalent to the BSD's 'tail -n100'?

Tags: unix, solaris, bsd, tail

I've looked this up a thousand times, and I always forget it, so, here for eternity:

Solaris has a bit of an awkward syntax for `tail`.

How do I do the equivalent of BSD's `tail -nN`?

What I want are the last N lines from tail's input.

Comment: I've never encountered a "tail" that required the "n".

Comment: What about an equivalent to "tail -f -n500 <file>"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just remove the "n"

```
tail -100
```

Comment: nice. I always remember that I need to specify -l somehow. Which would be -100l. Now I know I don't even need the l.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/tail
```

which does behave like you want (`tail -nN`).

xpg4 = Xopen Portability Guide Issue 4, contains binaries strictly compliant with several POSIX and other standards. The differences with the former ones are usually details in options supported and behavior.

According to your distribution, there is also /usr/xpg6/bin, /usr/openwin/bin (OpenWindows commands), /usr/dt/bin (CDE desktop commands), /usr/sfw/bin (Solaris freeware) and various other.

For instance, Solaris Express is introducing /usr/gnu/bin to provide Gnu binaries with their custom extensions and specificities.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-platform variant of `tail -n 10` for scripts:

```
sed -e :a -e '$q;N;11,$D;ba' file
```

This works the same for Linux and Solaris.